# Regex to replace domain within links that are not images

Tags: regex

Need to replace a domain name on all the links on the page that are not images or pdf files.
This would be a full html page received through a proxy service.

```
Example:
<a href="http://www.test.com/bla/bla">test</a><a href="/bla/bla"><img src="http://www.test.com" /><a href="http://www.test.com/test.pdf">pdf</a>
<a href="http://www.test.com/bla/bla/bla">test1</a>

Result:
<a href="http://www.newdomain.com/bla/bla">test</a><a href="/bla/bla"><img src="http://www.test.com" /><a href="http://www.test.com/test.pdf">pdf</a>
<a href="http://www.newdomain.com/bla/bla/bla">test1</a>
```

Comment: Can you give a few examples of the input (url) and the output (change url).

Comment: its difficult to do with a single regex - use a dom parser - see my updated answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the domain is http://www.example.com, the following should do the trick:

```
/http:\/\/www\.example\.com\S*(?!pdf|jpg|png|gif)\s/
```

This uses a negative lookahead to ensure that the regex matches a string only if the string does not contain pdf,png,jpg or gif at the specified position.

Comment: Remove the trailing \s if your links do not end in a whitespace. Use this: /http:\/\/www\.example\.com\S*(?!pdf|jpg|png|gif)/

Comment: tried running that against an example above, it replaces all the urls

Answer (score 2):

If you are using .NET, I strongly suggest you to use [HTML Agility Pack](http://www.codeplex.com/htmlagilitypack)
Direct parsing using regex can be very error prone. This questions is also similar to the post below.

[What regex should I use to remove links from HTML code in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2438267/what-regex-should-i-use-to-remove-links-from-html-code-in-c/2438292#2438292)

Answer (score 0):

If none of your pdf urls have query parameters (like `a.pdf?asd=12`), the following code will work. It replaces only absolute and root-relative urls.

```
var links = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
var len = links.length;
var newDomain = "http://mydomain.com";
/**
 * Match absolute urls (starting with http) 
 * and root relative urls (starting with a `/`)
 * Does not match relative urls like "subfolder/anotherpage.html"
 * */
var regex = new RegExp("^(?:https?://[^/]+)?(/.*)$", "i");
//uncomment next line if you want to replace only absolute urls
//regex = new RegExp("^https?://[^/]+(/.*)$", "i");
for(var i = 0; i < len; i++)
{
  var link = links.item(i);
  var href = link.getAttribute("href");
  if(!href) //in case of named anchors
    continue;
  if(href.match(/\.pdf$/i)) //if pdf
    continue;
  href = href.replace(regex, newDomain + "$1");
  link.setAttribute("href", href);
}
```